# Spring JPA/Hibernate not updating to DB for change of boolean for @Entity on save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

At some point my application stopped saving the `boolean` value for a `@Entity` when being saved by my `Repository`.

A `REST` call is made, within that call I set a `Device` to be `InUse` to true.

```
        device.setInUse(inUse);
        Device savedDev = deviceRepository.save(device);

        Logger.debug("Device after save isInUse() " + savedDev.isInUse()); 
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        Device dbDev2 = deviceRepository.findOne(device.getSerial());
        Logger.debug("Device again from db for isInUse() " + dbDev2.isInUse());
```

The output of this is `true` for both the device being saved and when issuing a `deviceRepository.findOne(device.getSerial())`.  The problem is when I go into the database and actually view the record it is not being updated.

I turned on hibernate debug logging and I can not see the update being made to the device.  When I save other `@Entity`'s I can see the hibernate query in the logs.  This leads me to believe that it is somehow caching this.

In the hibernate logs I see

- The parent object which holds a list of devices being loaded from hibernate
- (This is where the device should then be updated with inUse = true)
- Continues to load other details from Hibernate for Lists of `@Entity`'s from the parent but never updates the device...

**Question**

I wanted to know what could be causing this?

**Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    /**
     * Default index
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "runTestRun", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> runTestRun(@RequestBody String jsonObject) throws Exception {

        .....
            setDevicesInUse(testRun.getDevices(), true);
        .....
    }

private void setDevicesInUse(Set<Device> devices, boolean inUse) throws InterruptedException {
    for (Device device : devices) {
        Logger.debug("Marking Device " + device.getSerial() + " " + device.getReadableName() + " InUse to " + inUse);

        Device dbDev = deviceRepository.findOne(device.getSerial());
        Logger.debug("Device before change checking isInUse() " + dbDev.isInUse()); 
        dbDev.setInUse(inUse);
        Logger.debug("Device after setting isInUse() " + dbDev.isInUse()); 

        device.setInUse(inUse);
        Device savedDev = deviceRepository.save(device);

        Logger.debug("Device after save isInUse() " + savedDev.isInUse()); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Device dbDev2 = deviceRepository.findOne(device.getSerial());
        Logger.debug("Device again from db for isInUse() " + dbDev2.isInUse()); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }   
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database
# connection.
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Use hibernates new generator mappings, this is used for the appium port using a TABLE generator
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true

# Web server
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
server.context-path=/api
server.port=8082

# TODO FOR DEBUG ONLY
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.groovy.template.cache=false
spring.velocity.cache=false
spring.mustache.cache=false
server.session.persistent=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.resources.cache-period=0
```

I tried adding the following but it made no difference

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false

**Device**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {


    private @Id String serial;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean inUse;

    private @Version @JsonIgnore Long version;

    private Device() {
    }
```

Comment: After a cursory glance, smells like a transaction-boundary issue.

Comment: @chrylis       I can see the parent object being loaded form hibernate and then where it should be saving nothing happens.  When I reload the device from the repository it shows as it being updated but there have been no hibernate logs to show me it actually setting the device inUse or actually retrieving the saved device from in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the setup of Transnational as it was not finished the transaction thus sending to the db.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```